# What are the indecomposable modules over $\mathbb{F}_2(C_2\times C_2)$?

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, finite-groups, modules

Let $C_2$ be the cyclic group of order $2$ and $\mathbb{F}_2$ the field with $2$ elements. Consider the group algebra $A:= \mathbb{F}_2 (C_2\times C_2)$. It is well-known that $A$ has infinite representation type. Is there a classification of the finite dimensional indecomposable $A$-modules (and the Auslander-Reiten quiver of $\text{mod}\,A$) in this case?

Comment: I believe this is the same as representations of the Kronecker quiver https://arxiv.org/pdf/1209.4074.pdf

Comment: A quirk of $\mathbb{F}_2$ having characteristic $2$ is that $\mathbb{F}_2[C_2]$ is isomorphic to an exterior $\mathbb{F}_2$-algebra on one generator. Consequently $\mathbb{F}_2[C_2\times C_2]$ is isomorphic to an exterior $\mathbb{F}_2$-algebra on two generators. If you are willing to grade that algebra so that the exterior generators are homogeneous and in distinct positive degrees, then the fin. dim. indecomposable _graded_ modules are classified by Adams in section III.16 of "Stable homotopy and generalized homology," for the sake of calculating topological $K$-theory using the Adams SS.

Comment: An older reference than Benjamin's is S. B. Conlon, J. Austral. Math. Soc. 10 (1969), 363-366. This is probably the first place where the indecomposables  were classified over arbitrary fields $k$ of characteristic $2$. There are 4 infinite families $A_n$, $B_n$, $C_\pi(n)$ and $C_n(\infty)$ and one other $D$. The definition of $C_\pi(n)$ involves studying the irreducible polynomials over $k$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A complete description of the indecomposable modules for $C_2\times C_2$, including the Auslander-Reiten quiver is available in David Benson's book *Modular Representation Theory: New Trends and Methods*, Springer 1984, pp.176-181. This is over $\bar{\mathbb{F}}_2$; the result over arbitrary fields is given in the following few pages.